# SCSS : Checking if a value exists in a multi dimensional list

Tags: sass

I'm using Sass (v3.3.0.alpha.392), and I have a multi-dimensional list that looks somewhat like this,

```
$list: (
config: (
    foo: (
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
    ),
    bar: (
        a: 3,
        b: 4,
    ),
));
```

I have a @mixin that takes an argument, and will output based on which argument is passed if it exists in the config $list. Something like this,

```
@mixin foo($arg) {
    @if $arg exists in $list == true { // is 'foo' or 'bar'
        // Do something
    } @else {
        @warn "failed.";
    }
}
```

Usage,

```
.test {
    @include foo(bar); // should return true and run code block
    @include foo(data); // should return false and @warn
}
```

But, I cannot find the correct function to check if $arg exists in $list. I have tried small functions that check the index,

```
@function exists($n) {
    @return (false == index($list, config $n));
}
```

But, this don't seem to work (I might just be using it incorrectly). I basically need this to switch between different operations based on if the arg is contained in the $list.

Also, might be a double question, but is there also any way to check if the $arg is an integer or string? Would also be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$list` is actually a map:

```
type-of($list) == map
```

And if I understand correctly, you are interested in matching your keys to a value (e.g. `bar`).
There is a function called `map-has-key($map, $key)` that returns true if it finds the matching key, but in a multidimensional map it only matches keys in the topmost level. However, you can write a simple wrapper function that recursively apply `map-has-key` through all the levels of your map until it finds a match. The wrapper function could be something like this:

```js
@function rmhk($m, $a){
    @if map-has-key($m, $a) { @return true; };
    @each $key,$e in $m {
      @if (type-of($e) == map) and rmhk($e, $a) { @return true; }
    }
  @return false;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9042651)

The same way (with a recursive function) you can also match the values in your map in addition to the keys or traverse a list instead of a map ([DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9042283) with value-matching in a multidimensional list).

And, as already pointed out by @Jeremy, you can use `type-of()` to check for the type of a variable (like `string`,`number`,`list`,`map`,`color`), but if for some reason you need to check for something more specific you would need a custom function (for example, this short function for checking if a value is an integer: [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9043091)).

Comment: Perfect. I don't know why I was thinking I was using a list instead of a map. That's the whole reason for using v3.3. Anyways, both you and @Jeremey helped a ton!

Answer (score 2):

You can use type-of for your second question like so:

```
@if type-of($arg) == number {
    ...
}
```

for the first question, you cannot access a list with a non-numeral index so, your helper index($list, config $n) breaks.  I don't know why you are using a multi-dimensional list, sass isn't really built for it and there isn't really a need.  On a normal list using

```
@if index($list, $arg) != false {
    ...
}
```

would be just fine, my suggestion is to go in and refactor your code so it doesn't need the 2d list but if you must then you must and you have to iterate over each item on each level to check if $arg exists in each "list within a list" if that makes sense...

so you would get (my sass is a little rusty I dont know if @each is the iterating function on a list)

```
@each $list in lists {
    @if type-of($list) == list {
        @if index($list, $arg) != false {
           ...
        }
    }
    @else {
        go deeper
    }
}
```

This is ugly, and to get it to run in any kind of way is going to be a problem.  What you are trying to do is use Sass in a way that it is not, you are trying to make sass lists behave like javascript objects and they are very very different.  You should look into just using the new [map functions](https://github.com/nex3/sass/blob/master/doc-src/SASS_CHANGELOG.md#sassscript-maps) for their key-values which will really be all you should need to do anything (in fact making a map as a value in a map is what a javascript object is and you could do it that way)